# Can anyone explain why this website has missing data?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, api

I was trying to use the api that is located at:

https://api-r.bitcoinchain.com/v1/address/13gWtMQJdg3H6XBpFjMELcHLJc1HHp79vD

However, for every address I look up, they seem to be missing some transactions and subsequently have incorrect balances for each address.

Answer (score 1):

bitcoinchain.com is currently under maintenance, Please consider changing the website until they're back.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer to this:

The API queries the blockchain on a specific node. This node for whatever reason could not be up to date with the blockchain.

It could have even stopped synchronising with the blockchain from some date and therefore has outdated information.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, node from which api is fetching the data in not in sync with bitcoin blockchain.

Current block height - 504230 (blockchain.info)

And, api call to
 https://api-r.bitcoinchain.com/v1/status

gives height - 464428

Last block node got synced with had height 464428, which is far behind the lastest 504230 block.

Comment: Shame, they had a really good API, that did not cut off the inputs/outputs when there were like hundreds. Should have checked that before i developed the code to interact with their api :)